# Trouble creating a Regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regex expression what will accept a certain format of command. The pattern is as follows:

Can start with a $ and have two following value 0-9,A-F,a-f (ie: $00 - $FF)
or 
Can be any value except for "&<>'/"

*if the value start with $ the next two values after need to be a valid hex value from 00-ff

So far I have this

```
Regex correctValue = new Regex("($[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])");
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand this part of your question: _Can be any value except for "&<>'/"_.  Do you mean it should match any single character that's not in that list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add "\" symbol before your "$" and it works:

```
        string input = "$00";

        Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"^\$[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]$");
        if (m.Success)
        {
            foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
                Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Didn't match");
```

Comment: Well, I also added ^ and $ to mark the beginning and the ending of the regex

Answer (score 2):

If I'm following you correctly, the net result you're looking for is any value that is not in the list "&<>'/", since any combination of $ and two alphanumeric characters would also not be in that list.  Thus you could make your expression:

```
Regex correctValue = new Regex("[^&<>'/]");
```

Update:  But just in case you do need to know how to properly match the $00 - $FF, this would do the trick:

```
Regex correctValue = new Regex("\$[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}");
```

Answer (score 2):

In Regular Expression `$` use for **Anchor assertion**, and means:

> The match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the line or string.

try using `[$]` (Character Class for single character) or `\$` (Character Escape) instead.